# Click URLs of the clicks that did NOT lead to installs in the last 3 days

Tags: sql, select

I'm trying to return Click URLs of the clicks that did NOT lead to installs in the last 3 days

This is the table i'm using to solve the exercise:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9A2Ii.png)

This is the code i'm trying to use:

```
SELECT 
ANDROID_CLICKS.CLICK URL,
ANDROID_CLICKS.PARAMS_ADVERTISERID 
FROM 
ANDROID_CLICKS
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 
    ANDROID_INSTALL.PARAMS_ADVERTISERID
    FROM 
    ANDROID_INSTALL
    WHERE 
    ANDROID_INSTALL.PARAMS_ADVERTISERID = ANDROID_CLICKS.PARAMS_ADVERTISERID AND date-time BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE()-3 AND CURRENT_DATE()  
)
```

Comment: What error/output are you currently getting? Please can you also included your desired result.

Comment: Are the column names really as in the document; some with spaces, some with underscores, some with hyphens, mixed case? What a mess; Is it also testing your ability to quote identifiers? Your logic seems reasonable, you just have syntax errors because of the poor column names; quote them